# Error in parsing Json string cannot be converted to an object

Tags: android, json, web-services, parsing

I did a project from http://androidhive.com called android login and resgitration..when i run my project it updates my local server..but the app crashes with the following errors in the logcat

```
..03-04 09:40:47.284: E/JSON(22069): nnnnnInside config{"tag":"register","success":1,"error":0,"uid":"51346c28f08575.36974266","user":{"name":"sdfds","email":"sfsd@gmail.com","created_at":"2013-03-04 01:40:56","updated_at":null}}n
03-04 09:40:47.306: E/JSON Parser(22069): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value nnnnnInside of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
03-04 09:40:47.387: E/AndroidRuntime(22069): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-04 09:40:47.387: E/AndroidRuntime(22069): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-04 09:40:47.387: E/AndroidRuntime(22069):    at com.androidhive.httprequests.RegisterActivity$1.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:60)
03-04 09:40:47.387: E/AndroidRuntime(22069):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
03-04 09:40:47.387: E/AndroidRuntime(22069):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
03-04 09:40:47.387: E/AndroidRuntime(22069):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-04 09:40:47.387: E/AndroidRuntime(22069):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-04 09:40:47.387: E/AndroidRuntime(22069):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-04 09:40:47.387: E/AndroidRuntime(22069):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
03-04 09:40:47.387: E/AndroidRuntime(22069):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-04 09:40:47.387: E/AndroidRuntime(22069):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-04 09:40:47.387: E/AndroidRuntime(22069):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-04 09:40:47.387: E/AndroidRuntime(22069):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-04 09:40:47.387: E/AndroidRuntime(22069):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and my json code is

```
    enter code herepackage com.example.androidhive.library;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List; 
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class JSONParser {
  Context context;
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,HTTP.UTF_8));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.e("JSON", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }`enter code here`
}
```

i read all answers in stack overflow could nt get anything..pls help me thanks in advance

```
   package com.androidhive.httprequests;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.androidhive.library.DatabaseHandler;
import com.example.androidhive.library.UserFunctions;
import com.example.androidhive.library.JSONParser;
public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
    Button btnRegister;
    Button btnLinkToLogin;
    EditText inputFullName;
    EditText inputEmail;
    EditText inputPassword;
    TextView registerErrorMsg;

    // JSON Response node names
    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
    private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
    private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

        // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
        inputFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerName);
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerEmail);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerPassword);
        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        btnLinkToLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToLoginScreen);
        registerErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_error);

        // Register Button Click event
        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Inside btnregister", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String name = inputFullName.getText().toString();
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
                UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(name, email, password);

                // check for login response
                try {
                    if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                        String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                        if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                            // user successfully registred
                            // Store user details in SQLite Database
                            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                            JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                            // Clear all previous data in database
                            userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                            db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));
                            // Launch Dashboard Screen
                            Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);
                            // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                            dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(dashboard);
                            // Close Registration Screen
                            finish();
                        }else{
                            // Error in registration
                            registerErrorMsg.setText("Error occured in registration");
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        // Link to Login Screen
        btnLinkToLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        Login.class);
                startActivity(i);
                // Close Registration View
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

here is my register activity

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException 03-04 09:40:47.387: E/AndroidRuntime(22069): at com.androidhive.httprequests.RegisterActivity$1.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:60  post code of RegisterActivity

Comment: post relevant part of code because u have issue in json Parsing instead of getting json from server . so post json parsing code

Comment: Please post your `RegisterActivity` code for the line number 60.

Answer (score 0):

because you Json String is not Valid for converting to `JsonObject`. you will need to use String function first make it an valid json String then convert it to JSONObject as :

```
// your code here..
is.close();
json = sb.toString();
String str_json = json.replace("nnnnnInside config{", "");
String final_json=str_json.replace("}}n", "}}");
Log.e("JSON", json);

/// now convert final_json to json object 
jObj = new JSONObject(final_json);
```